# Avoid ClickJacking in java web application in spring mvc framework

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

Tried following solution : Added filter in web.xml :

```
<filter><filter-name>HTTP Header Security Filter</filter-name><filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

tomcat does not start with 2nd filter therefore not able to test clickjacking.
Giving following error :

SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CampaignDesigner]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name httpHeaderSecurity
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2975)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2940)

Appreciate early response. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I tried clening tomcat directory Also removed the synchronized project. Then restarted the sever by adding project again, but did not work.Also I did maven build then restart nut no good

Comment: `<filter-name>` in `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` have to be same

Comment: @akgaur Thanks a lot.I corrected it,  also had to delete all the existing servers and added them again after maven build.It worked